# C Data Structure theory and technique - ints and chars in same stack

Tags: c, data-structures

I am working on converting an infix expression to a prefix expression and have decided to use stacks to hold my expressions. I am using a linked list method for implementing the stack and am using the following data structure:

```
struct stacknode {
    char char_val;
    int int_val;
    struct stacknode *nextptr;
    struct stacknode *prevptr;
};
```

I have then written two different `push()` functions for `push_int()` and `push_char()`.

`push_int()` assigns a value of `'\0'` to `char_val` and then the value being pushed to `int_val`.

`push_char()` assigns a value of `-1` to `int_val` and then the value being pushed to `char_val`.

Note that all integer values being used are > 0.

I have then written the rest of my functions to handle the fact that the important value in each node may be the int or the char using the "negation" values of '\0' and -1 to identify whether the node is an "int" node or a "char" node.

Essentially, I am wondering if I am thinking about data structures all wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Will you always only be using a `char` OR an `int`?  If not, consider a `union`.

Comment: It will always be one OR the other and never both.

Comment: What I mean to say is, are you using a `char` and an `int` as an example only?  Is it possible that you'll either use one `struct` or another?  In this case, a `union` would be better.

Comment: The stack will be formed of stack nodes. Each node will have either the int or the char as important information and the other as an indicator of its "nullness".

Comment: So you are saying a union of two types and only one can be returned?

Comment: With a `union`, each field shares the same memory, so only one is valid at a time.

Comment: So not wrong just incomplete. Thx!!

Comment: You should consider using an array of `stackonode`s as the underlying structure. The doubly linked list is inefficient both in memory use and in performance (assuming each push/pop will malloc/free and manipulate the pointers). And simlpler/less error-prone.

Or, if you have good reasons to to allocate each stack element, you can probably omit the `nextptr` pointer. It is not needed, to implement push and pop operations.

Comment: BTW the term you're looking for is "sentinel value".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
If you are referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value, that is not what I was referring to in saying "nullness". Basically I was reinventing the idea of a union. I was saying that within a given structure, if the int was important, the char would hold a signifier of "nullness" i.e. '\0' and vice versa. Thanks for the tip, though. I didn't know that term and found the wiki page interesting.

Comment: @JoshuaCook: Yeah, that would be a sentinel value. The Wikipedia article is pretty constrained. You also said "negation value", which I presume was the same thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Doesn't a sentinel value signify termination? I know that '\0' is used as the termination of a string, but here I was using it to signify that the information stored in that particular char was irrelevant. Is there a char equivalent of NULL?

Comment: @JoshuaCook: Often, but not exclusively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there's nothing *wrong* with your implementation, I think it might be more idiomatic/obvious to use a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Then you could do:

```
struct StackValue
{
    _Bool is_int;
    union
    {
        char c;
        int i;
    } data;
};

struct StackNode
{
    struct StackValue data;
    struct StackNode *nextptr, *prevptr;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not have two stacks - one for numbers and the other for operators.

You can then apply the shunting algorithm - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

*EDIT*

Also you can avoid pointers - Just put an upper bound on the two stacks and store the index to the top element

Comment: Because I am explicitly trying to use a single stack. Thanks for the link though I will definitely check that algorithm out when finished with this task.